# How to convert the following list to json file in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hi I am new in python and I would love to convert the following data into a json file. I obtained this data set from Google Vision API. However, I have no idea how to approach this problem. Please help. Any type of help will be much appreciated.

The data set:

```
[mid: "/m/02wbm"
description: "food"
score: 0.8716073632240295
topicality: 0.8716073632240295
, mid: "/m/01ykh"
description: "cuisine"
score: 0.848469614982605
topicality: 0.848469614982605
, mid: "/m/01f5gx"
description: "eating"
score: 0.8267097473144531
topicality: 0.8267097473144531
, mid: "/m/01_bhs"
description: "fast food"
score: 0.6969127655029297
topicality: 0.6969127655029297
, mid: "/m/02q08p0"
description: "dish"
score: 0.6883306503295898
topicality: 0.6883306503295898
, mid: "/m/0h55b"
description: "junk food"
score: 0.6554489135742188
topicality: 0.6554489135742188
, mid: "/m/0krfg"
description: "meal"
score: 0.6400452256202698
topicality: 0.6400452256202698
, mid: "/m/0cp_p"
description: "taste"
score: 0.5145916938781738
topicality: 0.5145916938781738
, mid: "/m/0jfd5"
description: "lunch"
score: 0.5000766515731812
topicality: 0.5000766515731812
]
```

The desired format is this:

```
{
mid: "/m/02wbm"
description: "food"
score: 0.8716073632240295
topicality: 0.8716073632240295
},
{
mid: "/m/01ykh"
description: "cuisine"
score: 0.848469614982605
topicality: 0.848469614982605
},
{
mid: "/m/01f5gx"
description: "eating"
score: 0.8267097473144531
topicality: 0.8267097473144531
},
{
mid: "/m/01_bhs"
description: "fast food"
score: 0.6969127655029297
topicality: 0.6969127655029297
},
{
mid: "/m/02q08p0"
description: "dish"
score: 0.6883306503295898
topicality: 0.6883306503295898
},
{
mid: "/m/0h55b"
description: "junk food"
score: 0.6554489135742188
topicality: 0.6554489135742188
},
{
mid: "/m/0krfg"
description: "meal"
score: 0.6400452256202698
topicality: 0.6400452256202698
},
{
mid: "/m/0cp_p"
description: "taste"
score: 0.5145916938781738
topicality: 0.5145916938781738
},
{
mid: "/m/0jfd5"
description: "lunch"
score: 0.5000766515731812
topicality: 0.5000766515731812
}
```

It looks like I have four types of data within this set and these four types of data are repeated. Each four is split with commas.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What format is your dataset in currently? Because that's not a valid list

Comment: bro i have no clue..

Comment: Where is the data coming from? How do you store it currently?

Comment: client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    
    for x in range(0, counter +1):
        counter_two += x 
        name = str(counter_two) + '.jpg'
        path = os.getcwd()
        with io.open(path + '/' + name, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read();
        image = types.Image(content = content)
        response = client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations

Answer (score -1):

An example of how to write python objects to json format

```
import json
json.dump([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], open('a.json','w'), separators=(',',':'), indent=4)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to implement json.dump or dict() into json format?